# Google Tag Manager hits not visible in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

I'm implementing Google Analytics v4 in my android app through GTM. Container and code are configured according to instructions found here https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/. I'm getting logs which indicate that events are being matched to a rule and fired, but I don't get any data in Google Analytics. Logs look something like this:

04-23 22:01:35.966 V/GoogleTagManager(22149): putHit called
04-23 22:01:35.966 V/GoogleTagManager(22149): Sending hit to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: ul=en-gb, ev=value, el=label, t=event, cd=MainActivity, ....
04-23 22:01:36.026 V/GoogleTagManager(22149): putHit called

Please give some advice...

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue, I don't see events in the Real Time data but they do appear after a day more or less.

Comment: I'm also experiencing something similar. In my case I'm not able to make GoogleTabManager log a hint with the cd value (Screen Name) This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672360/how-to-configure-android-google-tag-manager-v4-with-google-analytics-universal

Comment: double check UA-XXX and GTM-XXX ids. Also check the data in an an unfiltered view

Answer (score 0):

Can you give one example of the log that looks like `/GoogleTagManager(22149): Sending hit to store PATH: https: PARAMS: ul=en-gb, ev=value, el=label, t=event, cd=MainActivity,`?

The hits may appear in the reports after a delay. Can you make sure that realtime reports also do not show any activity?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the "real-time event" or event under "behaviour" section?
because you might have some delay of event report when you check them under "behaviour" section. You should be able to find them under "real-time event" if your container is properly configured.